# Using angluar to create a Dynamic Form Designer and Renderer

Tags: angular, formio

We are trying to create an application which will have an admin interface for designing forms, and an user interface to embed these forms, collect data from the end users and send the data to a REST endpoint in Azure.

The front end is in Angular and the backend services are App Services in Azure written in ASP.NET core.

We looked at form.io which provides the form designer and embedding part, but the backend services, as it seems, is required to be on form.io platform. Is it possible to just use their client side designer and renderer and save/load form schema user data using Azure services? If not can anyone please point to any other option than writing the angular code from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible you need to follow these steps :

1/ Use form builder for form creation

2/ Get the generated json form definition and store it in data base as text or 
json column (you need a form entity with id, content,...)

3/ Retreive a form definition from data base and display it through the form renderer component

4/ finally use the needed binding of the form renderer to set/retreive form data (initial content, submit event,...)